# Php redirect with variable

Tags: php

I am trying to use

```
  header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/gamecode.php?gameid=$pw");
```

below is my code.

```
   <?php
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/gamecode.php?gameid=$pw");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","placeholder","placeholder","placeholder");
 //or die ('unable to connect');

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


 //create random table name

  $alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  $numeric = "0123456789";
  $special = ".-+=_,!@$#*%<>[]{}";
  $chars = "";

  if (isset($_POST['length'])){
  // if you want a form like above
  if (isset($_POST['alpha']) && $_POST['alpha'] == 'on')
    $chars .= $alpha;

if (isset($_POST['alpha_upper']) && $_POST['alpha_upper'] == 'on')
    $chars .= $alpha_upper;

if (isset($_POST['numeric']) && $_POST['numeric'] == 'on')
    $chars .= $numeric;

if (isset($_POST['special']) && $_POST['special'] == 'on')
    $chars .= $special;

$length = $_POST['length'];
}else{
// default [a-zA-Z0-9]{9}
$chars = $alpha . $numeric;
$length = 6;
 }
$len = strlen($chars);
$pw = '';

 for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
    $pw .= substr($chars, rand(0, $len-1), 1);
  // the finished password
 $pw = str_shuffle($pw);
 //using the $pw variable for the table name
 $sql="CREATE TABLE `" . $pw . "` (
 PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 PRIMARY KEY(PID),
 Name CHAR(15))";
 if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 echo "table was created";
  }
  else
 {
  echo "Did not create table";
 }



  mysqli_close($con);
```

above is the page i am trying to add the variable to the URL. I do get the the page redirect however it is not adding the header variable to the redirect as it should.

Comment: Change your `'` to `"` as `'` will treat `$gmid` as literal string, if you want a value there, either concatenate the string else use `"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php?gameid='.$gmid);
```

You need to change the quotes before the variable or You can also try with `double quotes` like

```
header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php?gameid=$gmid");
```

Answer (score 7):

use double quotes instead of single quote, so change to:

```
header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php?gameid=$gmid");
```

or

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php?gameid='.$gmid);
```

Double quotes, will evaluate variable values before producing the final output, which single quote does not.

Comment: Thanks for your quick post! I wish I could select everyone's answer's you are all right!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php?gameid=' . $gmid);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Why do we change that? Lil explanation will be better here

Answer (score 1):

`header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php?gameid=$gmid");`

see the quotes.... `"` instead of `'`.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with quotes and double quotes:
Change your line to this :

```
 header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php?gameid=$gmid");
```

or this:

```
 header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.php?gameid=".$gmid);
```

If you do `'$variable'` , it will be interpreted as string and :

echo `'$variable'` ; will show **$variable** as output .
But if you use "$variable" , echo will output value of this variable.

Comment: Does using the header require a session?

Comment: ok. i am using the example above with the double quotes, it does redirect correctly but its not adding the variable. when i do a simple echo it does echo the variable to the page. (i have to comment out the header) any ideas what would do that?

Comment: i was using $pw=$gmid but it wasnt working so i just went with the $pw.. do i need something else?

Comment: before header add this line $pw=1; and check if it appears in the link you are redirected to , if its ok,you have problem widh $pw, try to give it a value.

Comment: your suggestion does not seem to work. When i go to the page, it creates the table with the random name in my database. (like it should) so i know $pw is being assigned a value. I can echo it just fine...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36578/discussion-between-faceofjock-and-user2671430)